# Color rows if one of them contains certain text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the following values, in Google Sheets:

[image: 0]

What is the formula for conditional formatting that can do:

1) if the C cell in the row contains "Build Muscle", then make the whole row with blue text;

2) if the C cell in the row contains "Lose Fat", then make the whole row with green text;

3) if the C cell in the row contains "Mind Power" then make the whole row with purple text;

I've tried everything that I saw online but the concept of a cell that contains a specific text + something else inside that one cell is something that I cannot understand how to be implemented in a formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF($C1,"*Build Muscle*")
```

---

```
=COUNTIF($C1,"*Lose Fat*")
```

---

```
=COUNTIF($C1,"*Mind Power*")
```

[image: 0]